# How do I print the content of httprequest request?

Tags: java, android, http-post, http-get

I've got a bug involving httprequest, which happens sometimes, so I'd like to log HttpGet and HttpPost request's content when that happens.

So, let's say, I create HttpGet like this:

```
HttpGet g = new HttpGet();
g.setURI(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
g.setHeader("test", "hell yeah");
```

This is the string representation that I'd like to get:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
test: hell yeah
```

With the post request, I'd also like to get the content string.

What is the easiest way to do it in java for android?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can print the request type using:

```
request.getMethod();
```

You can print all the headers as mentioned here:

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
  System.out.println("Header Name - " + headerName + ", Value - " + request.getHeader(headerName));
}
```

To print all the request params, use this:

```
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames(); 
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
 String paramName = params.nextElement();
 System.out.println("Parameter Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getParameter(paramName));
}
```

`request` is the instance of `HttpServletRequest`

You can beautify the outputs as you desire.

Comment: Tip: also specify the type of the `Enumeration` (*e.g.* `Enumeration<String>`) to avoid unwanted IDE errors and make use of generics properly.

Comment: Adding `Enumeration<String>` also makes the cast to String unnecessary.

Comment: Or perhaps Enumeration<?>

Comment: To avoid `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()` as being separate statements, the `Enumeration` can be converted to a `List`: `for (String headerName : Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()))`.

Answer (score 11):

This should be more helpful for debug.
Answer from @Juned Ahsan will not specify full URL and will not print multiple headers/parameters.

```
private String httpServletRequestToString(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("Request Method = [" + request.getMethod() + "], ");
    sb.append("Request URL Path = [" + request.getRequestURL() + "], ");

    String headers =
        Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).stream()
            .map(headerName -> headerName + " : " + Collections.list(request.getHeaders(headerName)) )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    if (headers.isEmpty()) {
        sb.append("Request headers: NONE,");
    } else {
        sb.append("Request headers: ["+headers+"],");
    }

    String parameters =
        Collections.list(request.getParameterNames()).stream()
            .map(p -> p + " : " + Arrays.asList( request.getParameterValues(p)) )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));             

    if (parameters.isEmpty()) {
        sb.append("Request parameters: NONE.");
    } else {
        sb.append("Request parameters: [" + parameters + "].");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone also want to dump response like me. i avoided to dump response body. following code just dump the StatusCode and Headers.

```
static private String dumpResponse(HttpServletResponse resp){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("Response Status = [" + resp.getStatus() + "], ");
    String headers = resp.getHeaderNames().stream()
                    .map(headerName -> headerName + " : " + resp.getHeaders(headerName) )
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    if (headers.isEmpty()) {
        sb.append("Response headers: NONE,");
    } else {
        sb.append("Response headers: "+headers+",");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite @Juned Ahsan solution via stream in one line (headers are treated the same way):

```
public static String printRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String params = StreamSupport.stream(
            ((Iterable<String>) () -> req.getParameterNames().asIterator()).spliterator(), false)
            .map(pName -> pName + '=' + req.getParameter(pName))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
    return req.getRequestURI() + '?' + params;
}
```

See also [how to convert an iterator to a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511534/548473) solution.

Comment: Note, the `asIterator()` is a Java 9+ addition.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 colld you please explain your suggestion with more details?

Comment: The `asIterator()` in the `req.getParameterNames().asIterator()` is a method that is added and is supported in Java 9. Anyone who is using Java 8 cannot use this method.

Answer (score 0):

More details that help in logging

```java
String client = request.getRemoteAddr();
logger.info("###### requested client: {} , Session ID : {} , URI :" + request.getMethod() + ":" + request.getRequestURI() + "", client, request.getSession().getId());

Map params = request.getParameterMap();
Iterator i = params.keySet().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) i.next();
    String value = ((String[]) params.get(key))[0];
    logger.info("###### Request Param Name : {} , Value :  {} ", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content string and this string does not have parameters you can use

```java
String line = null;
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpHeaders class has entrySet method, it is better to use it:

```
getHeadersAsString(httpRequest.getHeaders());
...
    private static String getHeadersAsString(HttpHeaders httpRequestHeaders) {
        return httpRequestHeaders
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(pStringListEntry -> pStringListEntry.getKey() + '=' +
                        (pStringListEntry.getValue() != null
                                ? Arrays.toString(pStringListEntry.getValue().toArray())
                                : ""))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
    }
```