# How to convert an Iterator to a Stream?

Tags: java, iterator, java-8

I am looking for a concise way to convert an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to a [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) or more specifically to "view" the iterator as a stream.

For performance reason, I would like to avoid a copy of the iterator in a new list:

```
Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();
Collection<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>();
sourceIterator.forEachRemaining(copyList::add);
Stream<String> targetStream = copyList.stream();
```

---

Based on the some suggestions in the comments, I have also tried to use [`Stream.generate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();
    Stream<String> targetStream = Stream.generate(sourceIterator::next);
    targetStream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

However, I get a `NoSuchElementException` (since there is no invocation of `hasNext`)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:364)
    at Main$$Lambda$1/1175962212.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator$OfRef.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:1351)
    at java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:326)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

I have looked at [`StreamSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) and [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) but I didn't find anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an infinite Stream<E> out of an Iterator<E>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956515/how-to-create-an-infinite-streame-out-of-an-iteratore)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg euh i don't want to create an "Infinite" Stream.

Comment: @gontard that wouldn't matter in the case.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg `Stream.generate(iterator::next)` works ?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg That won't work for a finite iterator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods/23177907#23177907

Answer (score 701, accepted):

One way is to create a `Spliterator` from the `Iterator` and use that as a basis for your stream:

```
Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();
Stream<String> targetStream = StreamSupport.stream(
          Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(sourceIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
          false);
```

An alternative which is maybe more readable is to use an `Iterable` - and creating an `Iterable` from an `Iterator` is very easy with lambdas because `Iterable` is a functional interface:

```
Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();

Iterable<String> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;
Stream<String> targetStream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

Comment: Thanks, is it really a `view` of the iterator or a copy ?

Comment: Stream are lazy: the code is only linking the Stream to the Iterator but the actual iteration won't happen until a terminal operation. If you use the iterator in the meantime you won't get the expected result. For example you can introduce a `sourceIterator.next()` before using the stream and you will see the effect (the first item will not be seen by the Stream).

Comment: Would `Spliterator.ORDERED` also be a valid charasteric for any iterator?

Comment: @skiwi yes you are right - and actually SIZED is removed by the `spliteratorUnknownSize` method. I have amended.

Comment: @assylias, yeah it is really nice ! Maybe you could explains for future readers this quite magic line `Iterable<String> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;`. I have to admit that it took me some time to understand.

Comment: @gontard The line is still magical to me. Can you tell me what you found? Is it a `Supplier<Iterable<String>>`?

Comment: I should tell what I found. `Iterable<T>` is a `FunctionalInterface` which has only one abstract method `iterator()`. So `() -> sourceIterator` is a lambda expression instantiating an `Iterable` instance as an anonymous implementation.

Comment: Again, `() -> sourceIterator;` is a shortened form of `new Iterable<>() { @Override public Iterator<String> iterator() { return sourceIterator; } }`

Comment: @JinKwon It is not really a shortened form of an anonymous class (there are a few subtle differences, such as scope and how it is compiled) but it does behave similarly in this case.

Comment: The tricky bit with () -> sourceIterator is that if it's called more than once, it'll return the *same* iterator each time. This leads to unexpected results. So you're depending on the implementation of StreamSupport.stream() and spliterator(_, false) here.

Comment: @flup the stream could be use only once, so it is not a problem.

Comment: To prevent the problems above with reusing smae iterator, use the following: `Iterable<String> iterable = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")::iterator;
Stream<String> targetStream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);`

Comment: @Stephan I don't think it works (it will throw an exception at the end of the iterator).

Comment: @assylias I tried with an ArrayList iterator and it worked. However I passed Arraylist.size() method to limit()  method.

Comment: @Stephan if you receive the iterator from a collection it works indeed, but you could have an iterator with an unknown​ size, for example a database cursor like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232173/829571 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990744/829571

Comment: Lists.newArrayList(your iterator here).stream()

Comment: What happens when you go parallel in the stream? Must the iterator not be threadsafe to avoid concurrency issues?

Comment: @mmirwaldt You should check Spliterator's javadoc. In particular "*Despite their obvious utility in parallel algorithms, spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe; instead, implementations of parallel algorithms using spliterators should ensure that the spliterator is only used by one thread at a time.*"

Comment: Seems like Java features get "part way there" and then just stop. This is such an obvious omission from the Stream API!

Comment: @assylias [guava streams](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/ff696deb11d83a59e1befd4a146b96b5e8b8fd3d/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java#L83) implementation does not set the `Spliterator.ORDERED` flag. Would this make any difference for the specific solution?

Comment: @MarinosAn in my example the source is a list so ORDERED makes sense, but I guess that if the source if a set for example, it doesn't.

Comment: @JoshM. for whatever it's worth, they did it deliberately:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods/23177907#23177907

Answer (score 172):

Since version 21, Guava library provides [`Streams.stream(iterator)`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/21.0/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Iterator-)

It does what @[assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias)'s [answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511534/254477).

Comment: Javadoc: https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/21.0/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Iterator-

Comment: Far better to use this consistently until such time as the JDK supports a native one-liner. It will be far simpler to find (hence refactor) this in future than the pure-JDK solutions shown elsewhere.

Comment: This is excellent but… how does Java have native iterators and streams… but no built-in, straightforward way to go from one to the other!? Quite an omission in my opinion.

Answer (score 109):

Great suggestion! 
Here's my reusable take on it:

```java
public class StreamUtils {

    public static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> sourceIterator) {
        return asStream(sourceIterator, false);
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> sourceIterator, boolean parallel) {
        Iterable<T> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), parallel);
    }
}
```

And usage (make sure to statically import asStream):

```java
List<String> aPrefixedStrings = asStream(sourceIterator)
                .filter(t -> t.startsWith("A"))
                .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 94):

This is possible in Java 9.

```
Stream.generate(() -> null)
    .takeWhile(x -> iterator.hasNext())
    .map(n -> iterator.next())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Simple, efficient and without resorting to subclassing - this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Unfortunately these don't seem to work with `.parallel()` streams. They also appear a bit slower than going over `Spliterator`, even for sequential use.

Comment: Also, the first method throws up if the iterator is empty. The second method does work for now, but it does violate the requirement of the functions in map and takeWhile to be stateless, so I'd hesitate to do that in production code.

Comment: Really, this should be an accepted answer. Even though `parallel` might be funky the simpleness is amazing.

Comment: You really shouldn't be working with side effects and mutation.

Comment: *While takeWhile() is generally a cheap operation on sequential stream pipelines, it can be quite expensive on ordered parallel pipelines.*
Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)

Answer (score 12):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Streams;
```

and use `Streams.stream(iterator)` :

```
Streams.stream(iterator)
       .map(v-> function(v))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 11):

Create `Spliterator` from `Iterator` using `Spliterators` class contains more than one function for creating spliterator, for example here am using `spliteratorUnknownSize` which is getting iterator as parameter, then create Stream using `StreamSupport`

```
Spliterator<Model> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        iterator, Spliterator.NONNULL);
Stream<Model> stream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1** [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias)'s solution wrapped in a method:

```java
public static <T> Stream<T> toStream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<T>)() -> iterator).spliterator(), false);
}
```

**2** [guava Streams](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java) implementation (marked with `@Beta`):

```java
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring (Data) then there is a utility class *StreamUtils* which has two methods:

```
createStreamFromIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) 

createStreamFromIterator(CloseableIterator<T> iterator)
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.0/api/org/springframework/data/util/StreamUtils.html#createStreamFromIterator(java.util.Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

if iteration size it's known this is possible:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();
    Stream<String> targetStream = Stream.generate(sourceIterator::next);
    targetStream.**limit(3)**.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.iterate` does the job for you.
Simply iterate while it has elements and mapped them to next.

```
public <X> Stream<X> toStream(Iterator<X> iter) {
    return Stream.iterate(iter, Iterator::hasNext, UnaryOperator.identity()).map(Iterator::next);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Use `Collections.list(iterator).stream()...`

Comment: While short, this is very underperforming.

Comment: This will unfold the whole iterator to java object then convert it to stream. I dont suggest it

Comment: This seems to be only for enumerations, not iterators.

Comment: Not a terrible answer in general, useful in a pinch, but the question mentions performance and the answer is not performant.

Comment: Iterators and Streams are both lazy. Collecting the whole thing into a list before processing begins seems to miss the whole point.