# Getting the next item from a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to retrieve and remove the next item from a Java 8 `Stream`, without this `Stream` getting closed.

```
Stream<Integer> integerStream = Stream.iterate( 0, x -> new Integer(x + 1) );
Integer zero = integerStream.getNext(); // 0
Integer one  = integerStream.getNext(); // 1
...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking to actually use the removed items, or just discard them? For the latter, `.skip(n)` is the way to do it.

Comment: There's actually a section on this on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26596485/923560) and with an [Iterator-to-Stream conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511534/923560), I came up with the following quick-and-dirty wrapper class. It's not tested, and it's not thread-safe, but it provides me with what I currently need — removing and using single items while keeping *this* stream "open".

`PeelingStream<T>` provides a method `T getNext()` that shields away `someWrappedStream.iterator()`'s *terminal stream operation* semantics:

```
public class PeelingStream<T> implements Stream<T> {

    private Stream<T> wrapped;

    public PeelingStream(Stream<T> toBeWrapped) {
        this.wrapped = toBeWrapped;
    }

    public T getNext() {
        Iterator<T> iterator = wrapped.iterator();
        T next = iterator.next();
        Iterable<T> remainingIterable = () -> iterator;
        wrapped = StreamSupport.stream(remainingIterable.spliterator(),
                false);

        return next;
    }

    ///////////////////// from here, only plain delegate methods

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return wrapped.iterator();
    }

    public Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return wrapped.spliterator();
    }

    public boolean isParallel() {
        return wrapped.isParallel();
    }

    public Stream<T> sequential() {
        return wrapped.sequential();
    }

    public Stream<T> parallel() {
        return wrapped.parallel();
    }

    public Stream<T> unordered() {
        return wrapped.unordered();
    }

    public Stream<T> onClose(Runnable closeHandler) {
        return wrapped.onClose(closeHandler);

    }

    public void close() {
        wrapped.close();
    }

    public Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return wrapped.filter(predicate);
    }

    public <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
        return wrapped.map(mapper);
    }

    public IntStream mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
        return wrapped.mapToInt(mapper);
    }

    public LongStream mapToLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper) {
        return wrapped.mapToLong(mapper);
    }

    public DoubleStream mapToDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> mapper) {
        return wrapped.mapToDouble(mapper);
    }

    public <R> Stream<R> flatMap(
            Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper) {
        return wrapped.flatMap(mapper);
    }

    public IntStream flatMapToInt(
            Function<? super T, ? extends IntStream> mapper) {
        return wrapped.flatMapToInt(mapper);
    }

    public LongStream flatMapToLong(
            Function<? super T, ? extends LongStream> mapper) {
        return wrapped.flatMapToLong(mapper);
    }

    public DoubleStream flatMapToDouble(
            Function<? super T, ? extends DoubleStream> mapper) {
        return wrapped.flatMapToDouble(mapper);
    }

    public Stream<T> distinct() {
        return wrapped.distinct();
    }

    public Stream<T> sorted() {
        return wrapped.sorted();
    }

    public Stream<T> sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return wrapped.sorted(comparator);
    }

    public Stream<T> peek(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        return wrapped.peek(action);
    }

    public Stream<T> limit(long maxSize) {
        return wrapped.limit(maxSize);
    }

    public Stream<T> skip(long n) {
        return wrapped.skip(n);
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        wrapped.forEach(action);
    }

    public void forEachOrdered(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        wrapped.forEachOrdered(action);
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return wrapped.toArray();
    }

    public <A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator) {
        return wrapped.toArray(generator);
    }

    public T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator) {
        return wrapped.reduce(identity, accumulator);
    }

    public Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator) {
        return wrapped.reduce(accumulator);
    }

    public <U> U reduce(U identity,
            BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
            BinaryOperator<U> combiner) {
        return wrapped.reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner);
    }

    public <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
            BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R, R> combiner) {
        return wrapped.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);
    }

    public <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector) {
        return wrapped.collect(collector);
    }

    public Optional<T> min(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return wrapped.min(comparator);
    }

    public Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return wrapped.max(comparator);
    }

    public long count() {
        return wrapped.count();
    }

    public boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return wrapped.anyMatch(predicate);
    }

    public boolean allMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return wrapped.allMatch(predicate);
    }

    public boolean noneMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return wrapped.noneMatch(predicate);
    }

    public Optional<T> findFirst() {
        return wrapped.findFirst();
    }

    public Optional<T> findAny() {
        return wrapped.findAny();
    }

}
```

A small test:

```
@Test
public void testPeelingOffItemsFromStream() {

    Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1);

    PeelingStream<Integer> peelingInfiniteStream = new PeelingStream<>(infiniteStream);

    Integer one = peelingInfiniteStream.getNext();
    assertThat(one, equalTo(0));

    Integer two = peelingInfiniteStream.getNext();
    assertThat(two, equalTo(1));

    Stream<Integer> limitedStream = peelingInfiniteStream.limit(3); // 2 3 4
    int sumOf234 = limitedStream.mapToInt(x -> x.intValue()).sum();
    assertThat(sumOf234, equalTo(2 + 3 + 4));

}
```

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is a way to do this, but with some limitations.

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate( 0, x -> new Integer(x + 1) );
Iterator<Integer> iter = infiniteStream.iterator();
Integer zero = iter.next();
Integer one  = iter.next();
```

Alternatively,

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate( 0, x -> new Integer(x + 1) );
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = infiniteStream.spliterator();
spliterator.tryAdvance(i -> System.out.println(i)); // zero
spliterator.tryAdvance(i -> System.out.println(i)); // one
```

Given a `Stream`, it's possible to get an `Iterator` or `Spliterator` from it, or to query whether it's a parallel stream, etc. These are defined on the [`BaseStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html) interface, a superinterface of [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which makes them a bit easy to miss.

In this case we know the stream is infinite, so there is no need to call the Iterator's `hasNext()` method or to check the return value of the Spliterator's `tryAdvance()`

The limitation is that both the `iterator()` and `spliterator()` methods of `Stream` are *terminal operations* which means that after they're called, the returned Iterator or Spliterator has exclusive access to the values represented by the Stream. Further operations on the stream (such as `filter` or `map` and so forth) are not permitted and will be met with `IllegalStateException`.

If you wanted to peel off the first couple elements and then resume stream processing, you could turn a spliterator back into a stream like so:

```
Stream<Integer> stream2 = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
```

This will probably work fine for some things, but I'm not sure I'd recommend this technique in general. I think it adds a few extra objects and thus extra method calls in the path of producing the next element.

Editorial comments (not related to your question):

- Don't use `new Integer(val)`. Instead use `Integer.valueOf(val)` which will reuse the boxed integer if it's available, which is generally true for values in the range -128 to 127.
- You can use `IntStream` instead of `Stream<Integer>` which avoids boxing overhead entirely. It doesn't have the full complement of stream operations, but it does have `iterate()` which takes a function that operates on primitive `int` values.

Comment: Or you can just use `x -> x + 1` which is shorter and also uses `Integer.valueOf` (verified just now with 8u25 and `javap -c -p`).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. The original stream does get closed, but a new stream which behaves exactly like the old stream is created.

You will need com.google.common.collect.Iterators from guava.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterators.concat;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterators.singletonIterator;
import static java.util.Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize;
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;

private <T> Stream<T> peekFirst(Stream<T> originalStream){
    //This closes the original Stream
    Iterator<T> originalIterator = originalStream.iterator();
    if (!originalIterator.hasNext()) {
        return Stream.of();
    }
    T firstElement = originalIterator.next();
    doSomethingWithFirstElement(firstElement);
    Iterator<T> newIterator = concat(
      singletonIterator(firstElement),
      originalIterator);
    return stream(
      spliteratorUnknownSize(newIterator, 0), 
        originalStream.isParallel());
}
```