# Handle one element in a stream without closing it

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for a **clean and efficient** way to apply a consumer to one element of a non parallel stream without closing the stream.

I mean I want to replace

```
AtomicBoolean firstOneDone = new AtomicBoolean();
lines.forEach(line -> {
    if (!firstOneDone.get()) {
        // handle first line
        firstOneDone.set(true);
    } else {
        // handle any other line
    }
})
```

with something alike

```
lines.forFirst(header -> {
    // handle first line        
}).forEach(line -> {
    // handle any other line
})
```

I don't want to do two passes over the whole stream (copy or recreate the stream, `peek`, etc.), or just move the boolean/test to another location like a function wrapper.

Is that possible or is the fundamental model of streams not compatible with this kind of partial reading ?

Comment: @assylias that's "doing two passes over the whole stream"

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Streams are typically lazy so the first line will only "read" the first element of the stream and won't process the rest of the stream.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine In fact it doesn't do 2 passes with a non parallelized stream. This looks like a valid and interesting answer.

Comment: Oh, interesting. My bad then!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine That would be pretty inefficient if it was designed like that, as a `filter` and a `findFirst` would result to check all the elements of the Stream while not necessary (and that wouldn't even work for infinite streams) ;-)

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595020/getting-the-next-item-from-a-java-8-stream

Comment: @Alex It's very similar and the not accepted answer is interesting, thanks

Comment: If it must be done without a (more or less hidden) boolean (see my deleted answer!): leaving Java streams aside, can you explain how to distinguish (in any sequence) the head from the tail? If you can do that, then you can do it in a Stream.

Comment: @dystroy An alternative way of using it would be: http://pastebin.com/NkQLDDTE i.e. using collect. it generates 2 streams in only a single iteration

Comment: @Jatin This just moves the boolean in fact

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible because your stream pipeline is closed with each "final" operation. An alternative is the following, using the `Stream`'s iterator. You'll have only one iterator. I guess that's what you actually want since you insist on creating only one stream. However you'll have to skip the "functional" part.

```
Stream<String> strings = ... ;
Iterator<String> stringsIt = strings.iterator();
if (stringsIt.hasNext()) {
  System.out.printf("header: %s%n", stringsIt.next());
  while (stringsIt.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printf("line: %s%n", stringsIt.next());
  }
}
```

An alternative, with ZouZou's comments:

```
Stream<String> strings = ... ;
Iterator<String> stringsIt = strings.iterator();
if (stringsIt.hasNext()) {
  System.out.printf("header: %s%n", stringsIt.next());
  stringsIt.forEachRemaining(line -> { System.out.printf("line: %s%n", line); });
}
```

A final answer with all functional is actually the following:

```
Stream<String> lines = ... ;
Spliterator<String> linesIt = lines.spliterator();
linesIt.tryAdvance(header -> { System.out.printf("header: %s%n", header); });
linesIt.forEachRemaining(line -> { System.out.printf("line: %s%n", line); });
```

Comment: I guess you mean `Stream<String> strings` instead of `Iterable<String> strings`

Comment: No. I say that it is functionally not possible. So just skip the `Stream` part and use the good old `Iterable`. Plus, `Stream` doesn't have an `iterator()` method. The right tool at the right moment.

Comment: Stream do have an `iterator()` method. And the while loop could be replaced with `stringsIt.forEachRemaining(s -> System.out.printf("line: %s%n", s));` btw :)

Comment: Indeed, my bad. I fixed my answer.

Comment: As the question is closed, I won't wait for a better answer. Thanks Zouzou, assylias and Olivier

Comment: The spliterator approach is very neat!

Comment: @dystroy do you want me to reopen?

Comment: @assylias I'm not sure (I would have reopened if I was sure). The two QA are very similar but there's the `forEachRemaining` here to make it complete. Do as you feel is the best.

Comment: The question and answer are essentially the same so I'll leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only seem to be consuming lines, you can just grab the `Iterator` from it; note, code below assumes a non empty stream:

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = theStream.iterator();

process(iterator.next());

iterator.forEachRemaining(doSomething());
```

Comment: I'm starting from a stream, not a path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are describing is actually possible. Even the first code you posted is not something I would recommend using. If the forEach gets executed in a parallel way, your `if(first)` might not work correctly.

If the class that is holding your data is a Collection you can just grab the first one in the list with the iterator.

If you really have to use streams you can do something like:

```
// assuming getStreamFromSomewhere recreates the Stream and is not
// very time consuming
getStreamFromSomewhere().limit(1).forEach(doFirst);
getStreamFromSomewhere().skip(1).forEach(doRest);
```

Streams are [lazy](http://java.amitph.com/2014/01/java-8-streams-api-laziness.html#.VPWIr_mG8qo) so it won't actually go through the whole stream twice.

It is important to remember that the Stream API is not holding any data itself. Any call on a Stream is more like plan about what to do with the data and how it flows from source to destination. Random access is not a part of that.

Comment: One caveat with this is that you need to get two streams - if the **creation** of the stream is time consuming (think: opening a socket or finding a file on a hard drive), this will probably be less efficient than using the "iterating" equivalent.

Comment: @assylias You mean it can't start from a stream and just return a sub stream ?

Comment: This won't work: the stream will be closed after the first statement.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire which means that the 2nd stream will read the first line too, even if it skips it. Right?

Comment: What I mean is that you'll get a `IllegalStateException` when executing the second statement.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I made the example a bit clearer. The point is that it's not really possible without recreating the stream.

Comment: Indeed, but if it is the `Iterator` creating that is time consuming, you'll still pass there twice.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You're right, I just tested, it doesn't work without recreating the stream.