# From JavaRDD<T> to Stream<T>

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-stream, rdd

Is there a better way to get a `Stream<T>` object from a `JavaRDD<T>`?

This my current and obvious solution:

```
JavaRDD<T> rdd = ...;
Stream<T> stream = rdd.collect().stream();
```

I'm wondering whether is at all possible to avoid creating an intermediary list that will have to hold all the elements in memory at once.

Comment: Since there is a [`toLocalIterator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#toLocalIterator()) method, you could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24511534/5743988).

Comment: @4castle sounds promissing, does that avoid the all-in-memory-at-once issue? or would be equivalent to rdd.collect().iterator()?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spark at all, but the documentation says *"The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this RDD."* Hopefully that answers your question?

Comment: @4castle, Yes it does, thanks.