# Stream created from CsvtoBean finishes after single element

Tags: java, stream, opencsv

I'm using OpenCSV to read csv-files and would like to process the data with Streams. The OpenCSV website states however that they 'won't be using Java 8 for many years to come.' So I guess need to fix the Stream part myself.

I can have OpenCSV parse the whole csv-file to a List at once, and then create a Stream from this List. This works fine, but I rather have OpenCSV parse a single line when the Stream actually needs it. So I thought I'd use:

```
CsvToBean<DataElement> elements = new CsvToBeanBuilder<DataElement>(...).withType(DataElement.class).build();
Stream<DataElement> s = StreamSupport.stream(elements.spliterator(), false);
```

Where `CsvToBean` implements `Iterable`. But the Stream always finishes after just one item. I can't really figure out why. Does someone know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the IterableCSVToBean instead and then see if you can [convert the iterator into a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/how-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-stream?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) in your Java 8 code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. IterableCSVToBean and its Builder seem to be deprecated though, so for now I'll just stick with parsing all at once.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I should have checked the JavaDocs.  In CsvToBean call the iterator method and then convert the iterator to stream. 

Disclaimer: I am the project keeper of opencsv and I wrote the IterableCSVToBean, which is why it popped into my mind.  Andrew Jones updated CsvToBean to return an iterator which made the IterableCSVToBean redundant - which is why it is deprecated.   

Hope that helps. 

:)

Comment: No worries, thanks for keeping OpenCSV in the first place.
(And a bit of topic, but if you're the project keeper, would it be worth replacing interface CsvToBeanFilter with the standard Predicate?)

Comment: I cannot.  Currently OpenCSV requires Java 7 and Predicates are Java 8.  I made the mistake with 3.0 to jump java versions and it turned out to be too soon so I have a "Apache Commons rule" where I check a couple of Apache commons projects (lang, collections) and when they jump java versions I can consider jumping versions.   :)