# Java create Iterable<? extends SuperClass> from Iterator<SubClass> without warning

Tags: java, generics, java-8, iterable, method-reference

How to properly create an `Iterable<? extends SuperClass>` from `Iterator<SubClass>`?

Let's just say that I have an `Iterator<String>` and I want to use a method that takes an `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`. This is of course not possible:

```
private String foo(Deque<String> words) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = words.descendingIterator();
    return String.join(" ", () -> iterator);
}
```

The only way I found to make it compile was with

```
private String foo(Deque<String> words) {
       Iterator<? extends CharSequence> iterator = words.descendingIterator();
       return String.join(" ", () -> (Iterator<CharSequence>) iterator);
}
```

But I get an *Unchecked cast* warning. Is there a way to do this a clean way?

Comment: Two obvious problems here: `String.join` takes an `Iterable`, not an `Iterator`. Also, why are you using the supplier lambda expression?

Comment: Your question is the answer to the first "problem" you stated : http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-can-i-turn-an-iterator-into-an-iterable/

Comment: `.stream().collect(joining(" "))`

Comment: @BoristheSpider `.stream()` of what? `words.stream()` would be not be in the order I expect. You can create a stream from an `Iterable` with `.spliterator()` but you need an `Iterable` again. Anyway, the `.join()` method was just there for an example.

Comment: Not sure why you think that you cannot create a `Stream` from an `Iterator` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/how-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-stream. Do that and don't create non-compliant `Iterable` implementations; using lambdas or otherwise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I found what I was looking for and it was actually pretty simple:

```
private String foo(Deque<String> words) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = words.descendingIterator();
    return String.join(" ", (Iterable<String>) () -> iterator);
}
```

No need to use the wildcard at all.

Comment: Well, it's nice that you finally decided to accept your own answer. :-)

Comment: It would be interesting to hear your arguments against my first solution (upvoted by the community).

Comment: @ETO : I never said that your answer was bad (I upvoted it). It's just that this was exactly was I was looking for and answering the original question : *How to properly create an Iterable<? extends SuperClass> from Iterator<SubClass>?*.
In my question, I was just not casting it properly.

Comment: Do not call your answer ***the correct way***. Let the community decide the correctness.

Comment: First of all, I don't gain rep by accepting my own answer.
Secondly, the choice to select which answer is accepted is given to the one asking the question, which he choses based on what he was looking for. It's the way it is at stackoverflow and I have seen sometimes bad/incomplete answer accepted. That's not perfect but that's why you have upvotes to rank answers.
Thirdly, I edited my answer not to call it the "correct way" as you were right about the proper wording.

Answer (score 3):

You could try also:

```
private String foo(Deque<String> words) {
    return String.join(" ", (Iterable<String>) words::descendingIterator);
}
```

But for general case it would be better to create an utility method:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> iterable(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return iterable;
}
```

Then use it simply like this:

```
 private static String foo(Deque<String> words) {
    return String.join(" ", iterable(words::descendingIterator));
}
```