# Create an IntStream and a Stream<Integer> from an Eclipse Collections IntList/IntIterable

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, eclipse-collections

I have an [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) `IntList`. How can I

1. Create a Java `IntStream` from this list
2. Create a Java `Stream<Integer>` from this list

without copying the elements?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, intList.size()).map(intList::get)`. To get a `Stream<Integer>`, just append `.boxed()`.

Comment: @Holger You should post that as an answer. I was thinking the iterator would be the most efficient, but that's also doing constant time array accesses with an incrementing index, so it's about the same.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder feel free to include it into your answer, I don’t want to create a new one for a single line of code. By the way, the `IntStream.range` approach is even more efficient in parallel processing, as ranges can be split nicely (unlike an iterator).

Comment: When Eclipse Collections 10.0 is released, you will be able to call primitiveStream() on IntList, LongList or DoubleList.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) [10.0](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html#primitiveStream--) you can now call `primitiveStream` directly on `IntList`.

```
IntStream intStream = IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).primitiveStream();

Stream<Integer> stream = intStream.boxed();
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Holger's comment found a much clearer solution:

```
public static IntStream intListToIntStream(IntList intList) {
    return IntStream.range(0, intList.size()).map(intList::get);
}
```

After looking into the `IntIterator` code, it turns out the implementation is equivalent to this, so the below solutions are unnecessary. You can even make this more efficient using `.parallel()`.

---

If you're on Java 9, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210328/2643425):

```
public static IntStream intListToIntStream(IntList intList) {
    IntIterator intIter = intList.intIterator();
    return IntStream.generate(() -> 0)
            .takeWhile(i -> intIter.hasNext())
            .map(i -> intIter.next());
}
```

Otherwise, I don't see a better solution than wrapping the [IntIterator](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/iterator/IntIterator.html) as a [PrimitiveIterator.OfInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.html) and building a stream out of that:

```
public static IntStream intListToIntStream(IntList intList) {
    IntIterator intIter = intList.intIterator();
    return StreamSupport.intStream(Spliterators.spliterator(new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return intIter.hasNext();
        }
        @Override
        public int nextInt() {
            return intIter.next();
        }
    }, intList.size(), Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}
```

Either way, you can just get a `Stream<Integer>` by calling `IntStream.boxed()`.