# Converting an iterator to a list results in an empty list

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

I have the equivalent of, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/how-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-stream):

```
Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").iterator();
sourceIterator.forEachRemaining(source -> System.out.println(source)); // prints out all elements
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;
List<String> targetList = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(targetList.isEmpty()) // prints true
```

I've added in some debugging print statements to help me, before I figured out the way to do the conversion. But it turns out that the stream is empty. So I'm wondering if my contents or my method is not quite right?

Reading up on [`forEachRemaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) it says:

> Performs the given action for each remaining element until all elements have been processed or the action throws an exception. Actions are performed in the order of iteration, if that order is specified. Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.

It doesn't looks like it removes anything from the iterator, so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with the code, it looks like `forEachRemaining` does empty the stream. Without that line, the stream does not end up empty. The linked explanation of `iterator` in the question gives this default implementation:

```
while (hasNext())
    action.accept(next());
```

Which will empty the iterator. This is not the same as the [spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) which:

> invokes tryAdvance(java.util.function.Consumer<? super T>)

Not `next()`, but regardless, you cannot iterate twice.