# The cleanest way to create a list in a functional way from a list of lists?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<DataObject> dataObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Company company : companyRepository.findAll()) {
    for (Employee employee : company.employees) {
        DataOjbect dataObject = new dataObject();
        dataObject.setCompanyName(company.getName());
        dataObject.setEmployeeName(employee.getName());
        dataObjectList.add(dataObject);
    }
}
```

What is the cleanest way to write this code in a functional style in java?

Note that `companyRepository.findAll()` returns an Iterator, so you can't simply create a stream out of it.

Comment: "*Note that `companyRepository.findAll()` returns an Iterator, so you can't simply create a stream out of it.*" [How to convert an iterator to a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24511052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a `Stream` from `Iterator`, you need to create `Iterable` first and then pass its `Spliterator` using `Iterable::spliterator` method into `StreamSupport::stream`.

```
Stream<?> stream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

The `Iterable` can be created from `Iterator` through a lambda expression as long as `Iterable` has only one abstract method, therefore the interface is qualified for such expression.

```
Iterable<Company> iterable = () -> companyRepository.findAll();
Stream<Company> stream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

Now, the things get easy: Use the advantage of `flatMap` to flatten the nested list structure (a list of companies where each company has a list of employees. You need to create each `DataObject` right inside the `flatMap` method as long as its instantiation relies on the `company.getName()` parameter:

```
List<DataObject> dataObjectList = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .flatMap(company -> company.getEmployees().stream()
                .map(employee -> {
                    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
                    dataObject.setCompanyName(company.getName());
                    dataObject.setEmployeeName(employee.getName());
                    return dataObject;
                }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... and less verbose if you use a constructor ...

```
List<DataObject> dataObjectList = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .flatMap(company -> company.getEmployees().stream()
            .map(employee -> new DataObject(company.getName(), employee.getName())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It would probably be clearer to promote the `map` to the top level of the pipeline and confine the `flatMap` to `company.getEmployees().stream()`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I don't think I get you. Would you provide either own answer or a code through something like [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler)?

Answer (score 1):

Imo, there is no real benefit to using streams to do this.  I would stick with what you have.  You could make it more concise by creating a `constructor` in your `DataObject` class. Then you could do the following:

```
List<DataObject> dataObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Company company : companyRepository.findAll()) {
    for (Employee employee : company.employees) {
        dataObjectList.add(new DataObject(company.getName(), employee.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though they ask specifically for a "functional" way, sometimes it's better to KIS and just stick with what works and is readable. +1