# Parse the JsonArray result using Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream, gson

I am trying to get the value of a key from the JsonArray. In result, I am getting the JsonObject, in the below format

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "esindex",
      "_type": "esmessage",
      "_id": "4",
      "_version": 1,
      "found": true,
      "_source": {
        "account_number": 4,
        "balance": 27658
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the `id` of all those documents havig `"found": true`. The format of JsonArray produced is

```
[
  {
    "_index": "esindex",
    "_type": "esmessage",
    "_id": "4",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
      "account_number": 4,
      "balance": 27658
    }
  }
]
```

I am able to get the list of all the ids using the below java code

```
 List<Integer> documents = new ArrayList<>();
JsonObject result = esClient.execute(builder.build()).getJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArray = result.getAsJsonObject().get("docs").getAsJsonArray();
        while (i < request.getIds().size()) {
            JsonPrimitive checkIfExists = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("found");
            if (checkIfExists.getAsString().equals("true"))
                documents.add(result.getAsJsonObject().get("docs").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("_id").getAsInt());
            i++;
        }
```

**Can anyone please help me, to parse the JsonArray result using Java Stream API**

Comment: May i ask why use streams to filter when you can use elasticsearch itself to get the relevant results?
Assuming you are using the java rest client of ES, you can get a list of SearchHit objects from the response and then get the source of the document as a simple `map`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.11/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response

Comment: There are many JSON libraries, so please **always** specify which JSON library you are using, to help avoid confusion.

Comment: @Andreas I am using Gson java library

Comment: @OranShuster I am using jest client of ES

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realize that [`JsonArray`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) is an `Iterable<JsonElement>`.

With that realization, you search and find "[How to convert an iterator to a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24511052/5221149)", where you learn that you can use [`Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliteratorUnknownSize-java.util.Iterator-int-) and [`StreamSupport.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to do this.

```java
Stream<JsonElement> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
          Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(jsonArray.iterator(),
                                              Spliterator.ORDERED),
          /*parallel*/false);

List<Integer> documents = stream.map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
    .filter(o -> o.getAsJsonPrimitive("found").getAsBoolean())
    .map(o -> o.getAsJsonPrimitive("_id").getAsInt())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You of course know the size of the array, so you'll call [`Spliterators.spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliterator-java.util.Iterator-long-int-) instead, and you can of course chain it all together:

```java
List<Integer> documents = StreamSupport.stream(
          Spliterators.spliterator(jsonArray.iterator(),
                                   jsonArray.size(),
                                   Spliterator.ORDERED),
          /*parallel*/false)
    .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
    .filter(o -> o.getAsJsonPrimitive("found").getAsBoolean())
    .map(o -> o.getAsJsonPrimitive("_id").getAsInt())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```